# how to add transperent layer over silverlight page.?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I want to add a tranparent layer over my silverlight page.

Answer (score 0):

I use a `StackPanel` inside a `Grid` to do that:

```
<Grid>
 <!--- Here is my normal content -->
  <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0.8"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                   Text="Something on the overlay!"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```